# angularjs 1.5 injecting service in a component - uknown provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to **share a specific property** across different components' (different controllers in them).

Trying to inject a service that I created in the app module.
The service has get/set functions.
I created the service called SharedProperties. It's not accessible from any component in my app, says "Uknown". Why?

This is how my app is defined, and here's the very simple service.

```
mapotApp = angular
.module('mapotApp', [])
.service('sharedProperties', function () {
        var property = 'test';
        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return property;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                property = value;
            }
        };
    });
```

and  then in my component:

```
angular.module('aboutPage').component('aboutPage', {
    templateUrl: 'app/about-page/about-page.html',
    controller: ['sharedProperties', function AboutPageController($http, $scope, sharedProperties) {
    var self= this;

            //inherting global variable

        self.prop = sharedProperties.getProperty(); //UNKOWN PROVIDER ERROR HERE


    }]

});
```

This returns:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: sharedPropertiesProvider <- sharedProperties
```

What can I do? 
I tried injecting it in tons of places and still doesn't work.
thanks so much.

Comment: Add the service to your module `aboutPage`

Comment: I did, as you can see it's injected. But I want the service to be used by many controllers, not written again in each one

Comment: Then use just `angular.service('sharedProperties', function () {})`, without adding to any module.

Comment: Where should I put it exactly? Can you write the code with it? Thanks!

Comment: See this link - https://medium.com/@ok.bayat/share-service-or-data-between-two-different-angularjs-apps-on-the-same-page-d8d7fc830445

Comment: Oh okay, well they share the service between apps, I have one app, I just want the variable to be accessible from two components

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: The `sharedProperties` service is in the `mapotApp` module. Add that module as a dependency in the `aboutPage` module. Also the controller injection array doesn't match the function arguments. Read [AngularJS Developer Giude - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: Read also, [AngularJS Error Reference - $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) and [AngularJS angular.module API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module).

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava a service has to be registered to a module

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/gorork/pen/zbXZmq?editors=1010)** with your code.

Your shareable service is correct, but make sure to properly initialize your controller, as well as correctly inject `$http` and `$scope` in it (see how `$scope` and `$timeout` services are injected in my demo).